# A verb that means 'to run ineffectively or with difficulty'

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What verb can be used in place of 'run' when describing the way an overweight character might attempt to race towards another individual? Because of his size, this person doesn't move very quickly or effectively despite his efforts. I'm imagining a kind of run that involves a lot of huffing and puffing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gallumph](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/galumph).

verb (used without object)
to move along heavily and clumsily.

also: barge, stomp, clomp

Answer (score 7):

Consider ***lumber***:

> Move in a slow, heavy, awkward way.
> ...
> *‘A large and heavily muscled guard **lumbered** past his door.’*
> [<sub>Lexico</sub>](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lumber)

Answer (score 0):

The verb " **[to lollop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lollop?q=Lollop)**" springs to mind.

The Stay-Puft Marshmallow Man, also known as Mr. Stay-Puft, a fictional character from the movie Ghostbusters, lolloped.